# Repeat same user input for each item - python

Tags: python, range, user-input

I am in the process of writing a KWIC search engine. I want to let the user decide how many words should be displayed before and after the hit word (range). I have managed this so far, but the range is asked for again after every single hit. Do you know how I can let the user select the range only once, and then it will be used for all hits?
Here is the part it is about:

```
def displayKWIC (text, wordPos):

    global textSequence
    resultline = ''
    ranges =(int(input("Bitte geben Sie ein Range: ")))
    for i in range(max(0,wordPos-ranges), min(len(textSequence[text]),wordPos+ranges)):
        resultline += ' '+ textSequence[text][i]  
    print(text+': =>'+resultline,"\n", "\n")
    return
```

I assume the problem is somewhere in the ranges line.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The user is asked for `ranges` after every single hit, since `ranges` is assigned *within* `displayKWIC`. Because of this, every time `displayKWIC (text, wordPos)` is called, `ranges` is assigned anew.

To change this, you could assign `ranges` *outside* of `displayKWIC` and pass it to the function as an argument, alongside `text` and `wordPos`.